# C# casting question: from IEnumerable to custom type

Tags: c#, linq, inheritance, interface, casting

I have a custom class called `Rows` that implements `IEnumerable<Row>`.  I often use LINQ queries on `Rows` instances:

```
Rows rows = new Rows { row1, row2, row3 };
IEnumerable<Row> particularRows = rows.Where<Row>(row => condition);
```

What I would like is to be able to do the following:

```
Rows rows = new Rows { row1, row2, row3 };
Rows particularRows = (Rows)rows.Where<Row>(row => condition);
```

However, I get a "System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator1[NS.Row]' to type 'NS.Rows'".  I do have a `Rows` constructor taking `IEnumerable<Row>`, so I could do:

```
Rows rows = new Rows { row1, row2, row3 };
Rows particularRows = new Rows(rows.Where<Row>(row => condition));
```

This seems bulky, however, and I would love to be able to cast an `IEnumerable<Row>` to be a `Rows` since `Rows` implements `IEnumerable<Row>`.  Any ideas?

Comment: just a remark (not related to your question) : you don't need to specify the generic type parameter for `Where`, it is automatically inferred by the compiler

Comment: @Thomas:  I actually have a couple different inherited classes that implement different generic `IEnumerable<T>`, so the generic type parameter needs to be in my real code.  My example shown here doesn't need it though, you're right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

extension method to the rescue.

```
public static Rows ToRows(this IEnumerable<Row> source)
{
  return new Rows(source);
}
```

Rows particularRows = rows.Where(...).ToRows();

---

"Casting" is not a good fit for the problem.  Every `Rows` is an `IEnumerable<Row>`, but not every `IEnumerable<Row>` is a `Rows`

Comment: This is probably better than what I was thinking I'd go with, which was to override `Where`, etc. in `Rows` to return `Rows` instead of `IEnumerable<Row>`.

Answer (score 2):

You can only cast an object to a particular class if the object is actually an instance of that class.

In your case, the `IEnumerable<Row>` that you get from the LINQ call isn't a `Rows` instance, and the .Net runtime cannot magically convert it to a `Rows` instance.

Instead, you need to make a function that creates a new `Rows` instance from an `IEnumerable<Row>`.  The function should probably be either a contructor overload or an extension method.

Note, by the way, that standard .Net naming conventions indicate that your `Rows` class should actually be called `RowCollection`.

Comment: Is there a site somewhere that describes the different meanings intended by Collection v. List v. Enumerable?

Comment: `IList`, `ICollection`, and `IEnumerable` are three different interfaces; you can see the differences on MSDN.  Custom collection classes should always end in `Collection`.

Comment: Should my class really be called `RowCollection` if it does not implement `ICollection`?

Comment: Yes, it should.  It should probably (but not necessarily) implement `IList<Row>`, too.

Answer (score 1):

While `Rows` may implement `IEnumerable<Row>` that doesn't mean that any `IEnumerable<Row>` is a `Rows`, so the compiler can't just let you make that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that, while you can cast up the inheritence chain (Row -> IEnumerable), there's no reliable way to cast down the inheritence chain.

Consider the following:

```
List<Row> rows = new List<Row>();

// Fill the list
IEnumerable<Row> rowsAsEnumerable = (IEnumerable<Row>)rows;

Rows realRows = (Rows)rowsAsEnumerable;
```

Since rowsAsEnumerable was never a `Rows` object, how would the system handle the cast?

The answer is that it couldn't because even though a Rows object is always an IEnumerable, an IEnumerable isn't always a Rows object.

**Update**

Since I don't like to be a dream crusher, I'll re-itterate what others have said.

You can use a simple Extension method to make things a little cleaner from your example:

```
public static Rows ToRows(this IEnumerable<Row> rowsAsEnum)
{
    return new Rows(rowsAsEnum);
}
```

Now you can change your call to:

```
Rows particularRows = rows.Where<Row>(row => condition).ToRows();
```

Comment: I thought I was hitting this wall, but I had hope!  You're crushing my casting hopes right and left here...  :(

Comment: @Sarah: Don't worry; it is possible.  You need to write a `ToRows()` extension method.

Comment: @Sarah - I hate to hear I'm crushing hopes. While you can't directly cast, you can use one of the other work-arounds here (including defining Explicit and Implicit casts in your Rows class).

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
Rows particularRows = (Rows)(rows.Where<Row>(row => condition).ConvertAll(r=>(Row)r));
```

You could also add an extension method wrapper for the above (which would be the cleanest solution) so you could do something like:

```
Rows particularRows = rows.Where<Row>(row => condition).ToRows();
```

Comment: "Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<NS.Row>' to 'NS.Rows'"

Answer (score 0):

Basically whatever solution you come up with here is going to involve wrapping around that constructor which takes an IEnumerable

My original answer defined the casting solution (but I failed to compile and see the error).

What I would do is to define an extension method for IEnumerable:

```
public static Rows ToRows(this IEnumerable<Row> rows)
{
  return new Rows(rows);
}
```

Then you can use it quite cleanly:

```
public void Foo(IEnumerable<Row> rows)
{
   Rows r = rows.Where(r => condition).ToRows();
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to define an [explicit cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhbhezf4(VS.71).aspx) in your class:

```
public class Rows : IEnumerable<Row>
{
    public static explicit operator MyType(IEnumerable<Row> x)
    {
        return new Rows(x); // using your constructor
    }
}
```

This will tell C# to allow your cast:

```
Rows particularRows = (Rows)rows.Where<Row>(row => condition);
```

Comment: This looks promising, but I got "'NS.Rows.explicit operator NS.Rows(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<NS.Row>)': user-defined conversions to or from an interface are not allowed".

Comment: I modified the conversion... but you guys are wrong. This will work.

Comment: @David - You need to read up on explicit and how it works. What explicit does is say "It's OK to cast from IEnumerable<Row> to Rows and here's the implementation". Which will get rid of the error message.